# Silverlight UI element's 1-time binding to nested non-dependency property fails

Tags: wpf, silverlight, data-binding, binding, dependency-properties

I want a 1-time databind between a checkbox (IsChecked propety) in a childWindow and a nested member variable in it's DataContext object, such that only the *initial* IsChecked property is set by the member variable. The member variable (binding source) is not INotifyPropertyChanged or marked as a DependencyProperty- but I think that is ok b/c I only want it to be evaluated once- when it gets its initial value.

**Binding (in testChildWindow.xaml):**

```
<CheckBox Content="Show Username?" Name="cbShowUser" IsChecked="{Binding Path=User.showUser}"/>
```

**Setting DataContext (in parent window code-behind):**

```
  testChildWindow dlgBox = new testChildWindow();
  dlgBox.DataContext = (this.DataContext as IAssignDlgViewModel).AssignVM("defaultChildWindow");
  dlgBox.Show();
```

**Data Context/Member variable:**

```
public class testChildWindowViewModel : IDlgViewUpdate 
{
  public User
  ...
}

public class User 
{
  public bool showUser;
  public User()
  {
    showUser = true;
  }
  ...
}
```

If I make the Vm's binding source property (showUser) a dependency property at the (non-nested) testChildWindowViewModel, then the binding works.  But all other combinations seem to fail.

Why must it be a dependency (or INotifyPropertyChanged?) property for a 1-time binding?

Why can't I get it to work at a nested level?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ah, looking at the Output window during the binding answered the question for me.  The problem was that User was not a property.  Changed it to an auto property and the binding works just right now.